# What is the easiest and most efficient way to make a min heap in Scala?

Tags: scala, data-structures, priority-queue, min-heap

```
val maxHeap = scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue[Int] //Gives MaxHeap
```

What is the most concise and efficient way to use Ordering to turn a PriorityQueue into a minHeap?

Comment: Just for future reference, very often "easiest" and "most efficient" are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Easy to remember: `val minHeap = PriorityQueue[Int]()(Ordering[Int].reverse)`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You'll have to define your own `Ordering` :

```
scala> object MinOrder extends Ordering[Int] {
         def compare(x:Int, y:Int) = y compare x
       }
defined object MinOrder
```

Then use that when creating the heap :

```
scala> val minHeap = scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue.empty(MinOrder)
minHeap: scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue[Int] = PriorityQueue()

scala> minHeap.ord
res1: Ordering[Int] = MinOrder$@158ac84e
```

Comment: I think you don't even need to create your own Ordering, you can use method .reverse of an already existing one: Ordering[Int].reverse

Comment: for completion 

val minHeap = scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue.empty(Ordering[Int].reverse)

https://codebunk.com/pb/788100787

Answer (score 2):

Update August 2016: you can consider the proposal [`chrisokasaki/scads/scala/heapTraits.scala`](https://github.com/chrisokasaki/scads/blob/master/src/main/scala/heapTraits.scala) from [Chris Okasaki (`chrisokasaki`)](https://github.com/chrisokasaki).

That proposal illustrates the "not-so-easy" part of an `Heap`:

> Proof of concept for typesafe heaps with a merge operation.
>   Here, "typesafe" means that the interface will never allow different orderings to be mixed within the same heap.
>   In particular,
>
> - when adding an element to an existing heap, that insertion cannot involve an ordering different from the one used to create the existing heap, and
> - when merging two existing heaps, the heaps are guaranteed to have been created with the same ordering.

See [its design](https://github.com/chrisokasaki/scads/blob/master/design/heaps.md).

```
val h1 = LeftistHeap.Min.empty[Int] // an empty min-heap of integers
```